# Locked first element in android sliding menu

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments, android-menu

I'm designing android side sliding menu based on examples with navigation drawer pattern like this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >

    <FrameLayout>
...
    </FrameLayout>
   <ListView>
...
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

To achieve something like this:

[image]

In upper case we have view(2) as ListView but how to put in that menu locked element like (1) one, regarding to upper xml. I've tryied enclosing ListView in relative/linear layout like:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >

        <FrameLayout>
    ...
        </FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView/>

     <ListView>
    ...
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but it brings no result. Any ideas ?

Comment: So basically what you need is a section list view?

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout as below. This will work fine. Make changes in linear layout for your top user details.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/slide_menu_ll_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView />

                <ImageButton />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView />
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```